# MySql Query takes more than 30 minutes and takes 5 GB of temp storage and is crashing (no space left)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have the following tables.

deals table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `deals` (
  `Deal` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Action` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Login` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `Symbol` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Commission` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Volume` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`Deal`),
  KEY `idx_mt5_deals_Time` (`Time`),
  KEY `idx_mt5_deals_Login` (`Login`),
  KEY `idx_mt5_deals_Symbol` (`Symbol`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

daily table:

```
CREATE TABLE `daily` (
`Datetime` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Login` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Group` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Currency` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  PRIMARY KEY (`Datetime`,`Login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[daily table index columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiv1V.png)

The tables have a lot of records. In table deals there are 6 485 700 rows ( 2.1 GB of data )
In table daily there are 3 301 268 rows ( 1.6 GB of data )

The problem is that when I execute the following query, it takes more than 30 minutes and throws and error.

[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIQIU.png)

```
SELECT a.login, b.currency,b.group, a.Time,a.Symbol, sum(a.commission), a.Volume/10000,a.price
FROM deals AS a
INNER JOIN daily AS b ON a.login = b.login 
WHERE a.`Action` IN (0,1)
GROUP BY a.login;
```

Do you know for some approach that could optimize the request, and make  it faster. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any indexes on your tables ?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about the execution plan? What's the **exact** error message you are facing? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I've added error message image.

Comment: @Sergey Yes, see the scripts, there are indexes on deals table

Comment: and what about index on Login-column in the daily-table ?

Comment: well there is no index there

Comment: actually there is, I've added a picture in the question, refer to it please

Comment: Please add all details, like the execution plan and the error message, in text form. There's no need to add images containing pure text

Comment: @NicoHaase Here is the execution plan https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYFkD.png

Comment: Error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXWl0.png

Comment: your `daily` table creation has errors, because you are using column `Datetime`as PK, but you don't have that column in your table. Also, try not to use that reserved words for your column names (Time, Datetime, ...)

Comment: @nacho Okay, I Fixed the script

Comment: Also your GROUP BY may get an error, because you are only grouping by a.login, unless you have set only full_group_by to false. It has non aggregatted columns that are not in the group by condition. You should be very caerefull using it that way

Comment: @nacho This won't solve my problem.

Comment: I know, that's the reason a put it as a comment, not as an answer

Comment: The query contains incomplete GROUP BY. So only `a.login` and `sum(a.commission)` output columns makes sense, all another columns gets indefinite values and may be removes from the output freely without decreasing of query's sense.

Comment: The table `daily` have no suitable index for this query optimizing, and fullscan is used. Either create an index by `login` column or swap columns in the primary key definition of this table.

Comment: Do you need login wise consolidate value? If yes then why not aggregate the column price and volume.

Comment: @RahulBiswas what is that ?

Comment: SELECT a.login, SUM(a.commission) commission, SUM(price) ... GROUP BY a.login

Comment: @RahulBiswas Could you explain what is the difference ?

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Also, share pure text content (like the execution plan) **in text form** to make it better readable

Comment: Ran out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

- The error message indicates that you ran out of disk space.  The following *might* help with that problem, or you may need to get a bigger disk.
- `BIGINT` is probably overkill -- it takes 8 bytes.  `INT` takes 4 bytes and is limited to 2 billion; `MEDIUMINT` takes 3 bytes but is limited to 8 million.  Shrinking column sizes will help with speed (I/O) and possibly disk space.
- Change `Daily` pk to

  ```
    PRIMARY KEY (Login, `Datetime`)
  ```
- `Deals`:  `INDEX(action, login)`
- The `GROUP BY login` does not seem to make sense -- which time, currency, etc is associated with a `login`?
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`  If that is in its own "filesystem", it may be allocated too small.  (This sometimes happens with "/tmp".)